# How to format query to Month Name Instead of number in Spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet, array-formulas

```
=QUERY(G4:N, "SELECT FORMAT(G, 'MMMM'), SUM(H), SUM(M), SUM(N) GROUP BY FORMAT(G, 'MMMM')")
```

I tried this formula but give an error

Then i tried another formula

```
=QUERY(G4:N, "SELECT MONTH(G), SUM(H), SUM(M), SUM(N) GROUP BY MONTH(G)")
```

but it gives the number of Month instead the name

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a generalized example of how to use `format month name` within Query Fx.

```
=query({arrayformula(if(len(A2:A),eomonth(A2:A,),)),B2:B},"Select Col1, SUM(Col2) Where Col1 is not null group by Col1 FORMAT Col1 'MMMM'")
```

[image]

Comment: You just bite me. I was going to post `=QUERY({INDEX(IF(G4:G="","",EOMONTH(G4:G,0))),H4:H},"select Col1, sum(Col2) where Col1 is not null group by Col1 label Col1 'Month' format Col1 'MMMM'")`.

Comment: oops... sorry;)

Comment: No issue. +1 from me.